# Treeview converter issue

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, ivalueconverter

I have a wpf treeview bound to collection. The model collection is of type:

```
public Class A {
 public string Name {get; set}
 public ObservableCollection< B> Bs {get; set;}  
}

public Class B {  
  public ObservableCollection< C> Cs {get; set;}  
}

public Class C {
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<my:AConverter x:Key="AConverter"/>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type C}">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type A}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AConverter}}">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<treeView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding As}"/>
```

**AConverter.cs:**

```
public class AConverter: IValueConverter {

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

        if (value is A) {
            return (value as A).Bs.SelectMany(b => b.Cs);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The output expected is: A->C in treeview and not B. The issue here is when we add a new C the converter is not getting called to show the same in tree hierarchy

Comment: can you post code  without modification since initially collections were of `IEnumerable<>` type, now properties are private so won't bind anyway...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. Th properties are public and the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loose the updates if you apply a converter which does not return an [observable collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) *[sic]*. What you try to achieve is a bit of a pain really, basically you need to flatten the hierarchy while maintaining updates, this can be done using a `CompositeCollection` to some degree. e.g.

```
public class AConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var compositeCollection = new CompositeCollection();
        var a = (A)value;
        // React to changes of the Bs:
        a.Bs.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.Action)
                {
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        // ObservableCollection only ever manipulates one item, thus NewItems[0].
                        compositeCollection.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, new CollectionContainer { Collection = ((B)e.NewItems[0]).Cs });
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                        //TODO: Implement
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                        //TODO: Implement
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                        //TODO: Implement
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                        //TODO: Implement
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            };
        // Add the items for the current Bs:
        foreach (var item in a.Bs)
        {
            compositeCollection.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = item.Cs });
        }
        return compositeCollection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The implementation of the other cases is up to you, the insertions seem to work.

A better solution might be to expose `CompositeCollections` at every level, because then they can easily be nested, i.e. you can add a `CollectionContainer` having a `CompositeCollection` as its source.